# No such file while running a java project from Terminal

Tags: java, linux, unix

I run a java project from the terminal.
The project look for a file (that I know that exist) but i get this msg:
(no such file or directory)n: /root/dir/src/dir2/abc.txt
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native method)

I tried to convert the file to unix but it didnt help.
What do you think is the solution?

Thanks in advance, Guy.

EDIT: It seems like he is searching the file in:
n:/root/etc
and not in
/root/etc

Any ideas of why is it happening?

Comment: Code, please. And the full stack trace, and a comment in the code that marks the line that the stack trace says the error is in.

Comment: *that I know that exist* ... Yeah, I don't think so.

Comment: Edited a little. No reason for code - it works on intelliJ the problem starts when i run it from terminal

Comment: Does this user have read access on path he is trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that your path is correct or you can run javac command by going there

for example your file name is xyz.java and is located at d: in abc folder
then you should go to d:\abc and then run javac command
D:\abc>javac xyz.java